# TypeError (can't convert nil into String): Error

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I am trying to post JSON datas to server via Rails controller.
My ajax is like

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "http://localhost:3000/widget_denemes/getUserInfo",
    data: {userInfo: {mainURL:document.location.href}},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Successful");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Unsuccessful");
    }
});
```

and my controller is like

```
  def getUserInfo
    data = ActiveSupport::JSON::decode(params[:userInfo])
    format.json {head :ok}
  end
```

and also my route is

```
post 'widget_denemes/getUserInfo' => 'widget_denemes#getUserInfo'
```

but I see this problem on my terminal when I run the server

```
Started POST "/widget_denemes/getUserInfo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-15 11:34:20 +0300
Processing by WidgetDenemesController#getUserInfo as HTML
  Parameters: {"userInfo"=>{"mainURL"=>"file://localhost/Users/ender/Desktop/widgetTest.html"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

TypeError (can't convert ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String):
  app/controllers/widget_denemes_controller.rb:36:in `getUserInfo'
```

What is the wrong?
How should I fix it?

Comment: I think there is no html page for getUserInfo method.

Comment: I don't understand why your title includes "can't convert nil into String". Your error is: "can't convert ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String".